# istringstream invalid error beginner

Tags: c++, istringstream

I have this piece of code :

```
if(flag == 0)
{
// converting string value to integer

istringstream(temp) >> value ;
value = (int) value ; // value is a 
}
```

I am not sure if I am using the `istringstream` operator right . I want to convert the variable "value" to integer.

```
Compiler error : Invalid use of istringstream.
```

How should I fix it ?

*After trying to fix with the first given answer . it's showing me the following error :*

```
stoi was not declared in this scope
```

Is there a way we can work past it . The code i am using right now is :

```
int i = 0 ;
while(temp[i] != '\0')
{
  if(temp[i] == '.')
     {
       flag = 1;
       double value = stod(temp);
     }
     i++ ;
}
if(flag == 0)
{
// converting string value to integer
int value = stoi(temp) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you really need to do otherwise, consider just using something like:

```
 int value = std::stoi(temp);
```

If you must use a `stringstream`, you typically want to use it wrapped in a `lexical_cast` function:

```
 int value = lexical_cast<int>(temp);
```

The code for that looks something like:

```
 template <class T, class U>
 T lexical_cast(U const &input) { 
     std::istringstream buffer(input);
     T result;
     buffer >> result;
     return result;
 }
```

As to how to imitation `stoi` if your don't have one, I'd use `strtol` as the starting point:

```
int stoi(const string &s, size_t *end = NULL, int base = 10) { 
     return static_cast<int>(strtol(s.c_str(), end, base);
}
```

Note that this is pretty much a quick and dirty imitation that doesn't really fulfill the requirements of `stoi` correctly at all. For example, it should really throw an exception if the input couldn't be converted at all (e.g., passing letters in base 10).

For double you can implement `stod` about the same way, but using `strtod` instead.

Comment: It's `std::stoi` (you're probably thinking of `std::to_string`) :)

Comment: @novice7: have you `#include`d `<string>`? That's where `stoi` is defined. If you've included the right header, and it still doesn't work, you probably have an older compiler that doesn't include `stoi` yet. You'll probably want to write a small wrapper using `strtol` in its place.

Comment: yes i have included string header . how should i implement the strol ? also for a double , what should i do ? it says that the stoi is not defined in the scope . is that related to the header file too ? @JerryCoffin

Comment: @novice7: I've added a bit about how to use `strtrol`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `istringstream` is not an operator.  It is an input stream class to operate on strings.

You may do something like the following:

```
   istringstream temp(value); 
   temp>> value;
   cout << "value = " << value;
```

You can find a simple example of istringstream usage here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/