# How to convert DWORD to wstring?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to convert a DWORD value to wstring value.

```
DWORD dw;
wstring wstr(L"");
dw = 2;
```

Can you suggest ideal way to assign 'dw' to 'dwstr' ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring):

```
std::wstring wstr = std::to_wstring(dw);
```

Comment: Hi Chris, If I use wstr = std::to_wstring(dw), I am getting error as "more than one overload function matches for the arguments".  Please suggest to rectify the error.

Comment: @Rajasekhar, Try explicitly casting it to an `unsigned long long` IIRC. It used to only have a couple of overloads instead of all of them.

Comment: Will it cause any problem, if we cast from "unsigned long" to "unsigned long long" ?

Comment: @Rajasekhar Promotion from unsigned long to unsigned long long does not result in any loss of information. What sort of problems are you thinking of? (It sounds like you're having more fundamental issues with the C++ language. You might want to familiarize yourself with the type system.)

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I am new to C++ and I am developing applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an older compiler that doesn't have `std::to_wstring`, consider `lexical_cast` (e.g., from Boost) instead.

As an aside, if you want to create `wstr` as an empty string, just `wstring wstr;` suffices.

Comment: @JerryCoffin has `lexical_cast` been included into the standard?

Comment: @Koushik, No, it hasn't, but Boost is almost a must for C++ developers.

Comment: @Koushik: no, but if you don't want to use Boost's, you can [write your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15771007/179910) pretty easily.

Comment: @chris yes i agree with that. But would have been good to see it in the standard though.

Answer (score 0):

On C++03 you can do:

```
std::wstringstream stream;
stream << dw;
wstr = stream.str();
```